# Rearrange mission badges

Tags: ingress

There are some mission series you need to complete in correct order so the badges create a larger picture.

[image]

In case one managed to mess things up and made missions not in correct order, is there a way to rearrange those to fix the picture?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no easy way. However, if you redo a mission the badge goes up as the last mission done. So you can redo the whole mosaic missions in the right order.

This also mean you must avoid redoing a mission belonging to such a picture.

Comment: I tested this yesterday and it really works. Awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

There is currently no way to rearrange the order of the icons *manually*. Each mission icon is displayed in the order in which they were completed with oldest ones at the bottom right – and you can only get credit for a mission once.

You can, however, complete the missions again and the newest icons will reappear at the top.

Answer (score -3):

If you for examples instead of do mission 15 first do mission 16 you can re-arrange it. By doing mission 15 again and then mission 16. It will fix automatically

Comment: That's what the two answer's from 2015 already say. :-)